# Ways to create web pages with access to the operational system resources

Tags: javascript

I am considering a browser a program that run on the host machine and a script a program that runs on the browser. The browser gives some resources of the host to the scripts like audio and video, but not all the resources for security reasons.

I am looking for new ways to give the scripts access to all the resources of the host with the user explicitly allowing so. I know that node.js with webkit is one way.

Comment: Learn about web sockets and HTML5 drag & drop.

Comment: Most of the programming languages you can use for backend should be able to do this. Most of them has built libraries for these. (Node, Java, Python to name a few)

Comment: HTML5 drag & drop does not allow full access to the hardrive like writting and listing files in a directory. Also websockets are limited in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Browser are very restrictive when it comes to accessing user files. They have a lot of security, all with very good reason.

However, there are ways to access local files, as long as the user explicitly does the action.

Example:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Solution #1 creates a "choose file" dialog. You can read more about the `<input>` tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Alternative solutions could include a "drag and drop", there is a whole article about it here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/drag-files-into-the-browser-from-the-desktop-HTML5.html#fbid=I9bIgVPEIoR

As for sockets... there is a rather new technology called `websockets`. It takes a special server that is capable of `upgrading` the HTTP connection to a websocket TCP connection.

You can read more here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: That would only allow read access, not write access. Also websockets are limited compared to regular sockets.